# How to use set_data with semilogx?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently doing,

```
self.fig = Figure()
self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
self.axes.semilogx(omega,mag,*args,**kwargs)
```

I would like to use `set_data` to only change the data points.
How to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save a reference to the artist:

```
line = self.axes.semilogx(omega, mag, *args, **kwargs)[0]
```

And then you can use the `set_data` method:

```
line.set_data(omega_new, mag_new)
```

Comment: What are `omega_new` and `mag_new`, in this case?

Comment: Well, they are the new data points that you want to plot. Since you didn't provide them in your question, I named them illustratively